# Eclipse ide unable to locate files in localhost

Tags: eclipse, php

I am trying to get "hello" to pop up on a web page using localhost.

**Software involved:**

- OS: Ubuntu 12.04
- Eclipse IDE, configured for PHP
- Apache installed from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

---

**Problem:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DrJv.png

I tried to run eclipse from command prompt with `sudo` and it still did not work. 
I am also new to Ubuntu and not very familiar with how the directory system works.

Comment: Is you `newfile.php` file put in the path `/var/www/echo/`, where `echo` is a folder? If not you have to place it ther, to get it working in that url.

Comment: no it was not I am now placing my file in /var/wwww and re trying

Comment: Thanks it has worked. I did not know that localhoast was a substitute for var/www, so I was actually doing localhoast/var/www/file.php, which is redundant. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven’t made any changes to the default apache config so the apache server is looking for your files in /var/www/

You need to learn about Apache and configuring it there is an abundance of info out there.

the quick and easy way to fix this for development use only is:

`sudo ln -s /path/to/project /var/www`

Comment: indeed, learn about apache and add your 'site' to apache. Does this post help you: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=794248#2 ?

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that the apache was looking for the files in var/www. Once i figured that out, it only took a couple minutes to get everything working. Thank you very much for your response. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @user1599755 No problem, the path is long but fun. Please mark answered.